# Adobe Flash ActionScript 1.0 .fla file

Tags: flash, actionscript

how can i edit it, with which program? I have been looking for it whole day, downloaded some adobe terials.
Adobe CC animator have no support for ActionScript 1.0 anymore.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find an older version of Flash. But since Adobe won't give you an older version, you might have to use an opensource solution, like this one just for example https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler It can edit an fla and supports ActionScript 1